# Show hours in user's timezone in view

Tags: php, datetime, yii2

I want to show the quiz hours in the user's timezone in the table that shows all the created quizes and when view details of a quiz and edit.
When a user creates a quiz it chooses the hours with his timezone and when saving into database its converted to UTC time, but when its displayed the table with all the quizes it show the UTC time and i want to show in the user's local time.

What ive done so far in views/quiz/index.php

```
'attribute'=>'active_from',
        'value'=>function ($model, $key, $index, $widget) {
            $userTZ= new \DateTimeZone(Userzone::find()->where(['userUserId' => Yii::$app->user->id])->one()->timezone);
            $date = new \DateTime( $model->active_from, $userTZ );
            return $date;
        },
```

Its shows an error saying "htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given"
Did the same thing in view.php and shows the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is `formatter` component in Yii 2 for this kind of things.

```
$timezone = 'UTC'; // default timezone
// change timezone for non-guests only
if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
    $userzone = Userzone::find()->where(['userUserId' => Yii::$app->user->id])->limit(1)->one();
    // check first if data is present
    if (!empty($userzone->timezone)) {
        $timezone = $userzone->timezone;
    }
}
// set timezone for formatter
Yii::$app->formatter->timeZone = $timezone;

// now display the date in this timezone
echo Yii::$app->formatter->asDatetime($model->active_from);
```

It's better of course to initialize the formatter with proper timezone when user logs in so you don't have to do this every time.

One of the ways to do it is to extend `yii\i18n\Formatter` class with your own where the whole process of getting the user's timezone and setting it in the formatter is done i.e. in the `init()` method. Now all you need to do is to configure this component to use your class like:

```
// ...
'components' => [
    // ...
    'formatter' => [
        'class' => 'your\class\namespace\for\Formatter'
    ],
],
```

More about formatter in Yii 2 [docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-i18n-formatter.html) and [Guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-formatting.html).

Comment: Got it, but my question is how to initialize this formatter and call it in other fields that need to be converted?